# How to get start and end date of a command with the 'time' command in linux?

Tags: linux

I'm doing some data transfers and using the 'time' command to measure how long it takes for the transfer to complete. The command is `time bbcp source destination` Unfortunately it doesn't show the start and end date, only the number of seconds the command took to run. Is there any way to do this without complicated scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to call date, before and after, like:

```
date; bbcp source destination; date
```

with output like:

```
Tue Jun 21 14:48:32 CEST 2022
... the tool output ...
Tue Jun 21 14:48:34 CEST 2022
```

if you want a date format that is parsable you can do

```
date +%s; bbcp source destination; date +%s
```

with output like (the numbers are seconds since epoch):

```
1655815745
... the tool output ...
1655815747
```

Comment: Will this also give me the time?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't kill me for such a simple answer, but if I want to do something like this, I use this command for knowing the current time (accuracy in milliseconds `date +"%T.%3N"`), as follows:

```
Prompt> date +"%T.%3N"
Prompt> Launch_Whatever
Prompt> date +"%T.%3N"
```

This shows me two dates, which I can subtract from each other in order to know the duration. If your `Launch_Whatever` generates a lot of output, you might always capture the timestamps in a temporary file:

```
Prompt> date +"%T.%3N" >/tmp/datetime.txt
Prompt> Launch_Whatever
Prompt> date +"%T.%3N" >>/tmp/datetime.txt
```

The first one creates the `datetime.txt` file, the second one adds the next entry.